# Android - Room query always returns row's id=0?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a query like this in my room Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_data ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1")
suspend fun getFirstItem(): MyEntity?
```

and MyEntity is just a data class with an auto generated id.

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_data")
data class MyEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date_created")
    var dateCreated: String? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    var description: String? = null
)
```

When I run the query the entity object that is returned has always id=0.
How can I get the actual id of the row using a query in room?

EDIT: This is the function I'm calling the query

```
suspend fun getFirstItem(context: Context): MyEntity? {
    val db = MyDatabase.getDb(context)
    return db.MyDao().getFirstItem()
}
```

The returned MyEntity object is something like this.

`MyEntity(id=0, dateCreated="2022-12-07 09:38:37", description="some description")`

Where the id is always returned as 0, although it isn't actually 0

Comment: check your database in the device it might be saving the id to a value of 0

Comment: I've checked the database and the ids are saved as they should, with proper auto incrementing values.

Comment: I don't know, edit the question and provide your implementation of the function if you may

Comment: try to change the id's default value to null instead of 0 in your model

Answer (score 0):

In My System, Your Query works Properly.

**All Available Entries**
[image]

**Query Result**
[image]

Do **invalid catch/Restart** and Try again

Comment: Yes the query works properly. It's the returned object MyEntity that doesn't get the actual row's id but is returned as 0

Comment: I don't think you understood my question..

Comment: In My system, Your Code is working perfectly. I have checked I don't know way its not working in my system.